# How to create a search functionality in php from two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently having this problem for my project in a certain subject. I was wondering if it is possible to create a search function from two tables in mysql.
I can't really explain it with words so i'll provide code for this.

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
                <th>Date of Request</th>
                <th>Brand</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Plate Number</th>
                <th>Problem Description</th>
                <th>Parts Replaced</th>
                <th>Date Repair Completed</th>


            <th></th>
            <?php
                require_once("db_open.php");
                $sql = "SELECT v.*, rt.* FROM vehicle v, repair_transaction rt WHERE v.Vehicle_Id = rt.Vehicle_Id 
                ORDER BY Date_of_repair_request ASC";
                $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["Date_of_repair_request"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["Brand"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["Model"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["Plate_No"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["Problem_Description"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["Parts_replaced"]."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row["Date_Repair_Completed_by_Maintenance"]."</td>";

                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<p>No transaction to show...</p>";
                }
```

This is the code and image for the two tables.

Comment: What search functionality your expecting ?  do you want to search the mysql table with values?

Comment: sorry im just new.. i dont know how to display image yet.

Comment: Yes, I want to search a specific table row with values. I know how to search a table row with a certain value, but I don't know if a displayed table row from two tables is possible to be searched.

Comment: Try giving instances of the two tables you want to query and please mention what you want out of that.

Comment: What I have thought you have to search on html table. After the data has been displayed? Right?

Answer (score 0):

```
      <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>      
              <th>Date of Request</th>
              <th>Brand</th>
              <th>Model</th>
              <th>Plate Number</th>
              <th>Problem Description</th>
              <th>Parts Replaced</th>
              <th>Date Repair Completed</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <form action="" method="post">      
              <th></th>
              <th><input type="text" name="search_brand"></th>
              <th>Input for modal</th>
              <th>Input for Plate Number</th>
              <th>Input for Problem Description</th>
              <th>Input for Parts Replaced</th>
              <th>Input for Date Repair Completed</th>
              <th><input type="submit" name="search" value="search"></th>
             </form> 
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <?php
            require_once("db_open.php");
            if(isset($_POST['search_brand']))
            {
              $search_brand = $_POST['search_brand'];
              $search_brand_cond = ($search_brand!="")?" v.brand='$search_brand'":"1=1";
            }
            else
            {
              $search_brand_cond = "1=1";  
            }

            // You can use same code for all input

            $sql = "SELECT v.*, rt.* FROM vehicle v, repair_transaction rt WHERE v.Vehicle_Id = rt.Vehicle_Id AND $search_brand_cond 
            ORDER BY Date_of_repair_request ASC";
            $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["Date_of_repair_request"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["Brand"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["Model"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["Plate_No"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["Problem_Description"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["Parts_replaced"]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row["Date_Repair_Completed_by_Maintenance"]."</td>";

                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p>No transaction to show...</p>";
            }
         ?>
```